# How does WinForms label control handle focus?

Tags: winforms, events, focus, label

Folks,

There is a panel which contains 2 components: a label and a TreeView. The hierarchy, obviously, looks like this:

```
panel1  // handles Enter event
   - label1
   - treeView1
```

I need to do some UI updates when user starts interacting with any of these 3 controls. My attempted strategy was to catch the `Enter` event of the `panel1`, which would fire when user clicks the label or the TreeView. This way, I would write only a single event handler instead of several. While it worked for the TreeView, it didn't work for the label. When I click the label, I don't get the `Enter` event on the panel. What’s different about the label control?

I could handle the Click event of the label. At the same time, I wonder if there is a more elegant solution.

Any suggestion, insight or reference is really appreciated! 
- Nick

P.S.  I'm running VS2008 and .NET 3.5